# Querying django migrations table

Tags: django, django-views, django-migrations

How can one query the django_migrations table from a view? For instance(What I have tried and of course not working)

```
from django.db import migrations

latest_migration = migrations.objects.all().order_by('-applied')[0]
```

If possible, how should one proceed?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The migration model is defined in [`django.db.migrations.recorder`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.0.4/django/db/migrations/recorder.py#L22). So you can should change your example code slightly:

```
from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
latest_migration = MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.order_by('-applied')[0]
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Works for me on Django 3.2.  I wish the use of this model was documented, but there's not a single reference (that I can find) to MigrationRecorder on docs.djangoproject.com.